# Message telling me that I bought something with credit card

Tags: spoofing, scam

I just received a message via SMS that I bought something from an online shop with my credit card. The message reads like this (translated from German):

> Your credit card purchase - please check: - shop lampe.de: - amount
>   86,58 currency EUR - TAN 716500. Questions: 0721/1209-66001 selection
>   3.

Original Message:

> Ihr Einkauf mit Kreditkarte - bitte pruefen: - Haendler lampe.de:
>   - Betrag 86,58 Währung EUR - TAN 716500. Bei Fragen: 0721/1209-66001 Auswahl 3.

Notes:

- I recently changed my mobile number and did not yet provide it at any of my credit card service providers
- The given telephone number is valid (belongs to a big popular German bank)
- The given online shop is valid (https://www.lampe.de/)
- I once received another short message from a delivery service which raises the assumption that the previous owner of my newly acquired telephone number has still some services configured to use that one

Is this a fraud? If yes, how do I react?

Comment: Call your credit card company and check what's the number associated. If it's not this number better ignore the message as this could be a scam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are this is scam attempting to get you to call the number listed (which does probably not, as you think, belong to any real banking institution but is most surely heavily taxed).

If you have *any* doubt, your best option is to **call your credit card company** - the relevant number must be printed on your card - and **ask them about it**: they can verify what transaction was made with your CC and you might be able to dispute the charge right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this. If you don't tell your provider your new number they won't send you messages to this number.

This could be fraud or a message to an user, who had this number before. In both cases your account won't be charged and you can ignore the message